# Htaccess rule for a rewrite with parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, parameters, url-rewriting

So my current URL is: https://example.com/uDoc?id=xx

Using the rewrite, I'd like it to be https://example.com/display?id=xx&type=doc

The real problem is, that because I also have a rule(`RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]`) for silently adding the .php (uDoc?id=xx -> uDoc.php?id=xx, without it, it would result in a 404 error).
Which is somewhat interfering with the current answer given.

I have fiddled around with various htaccess rules, but I got no good results :(

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me, when it comes to htaccess rules, I'm totally giving up...

Comment: The current answer was my best try, but as I said, it somehow interferes with my .php rule

Comment: Ok, I've just changed all the links now, so there is no need for this anymore, I'll accept the current answer, as it does do what I asked before, whether my previous rule conflicts with it or not.
Thanks for your help though! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^uDoc/?$ display?type=doc [L,QSA,NC]
```

`QSA` flag ensures your existing query string i.e. `id=xx` is carried over to new URI.

Comment: Hmm it is not working, it just goes to the same page like it always would, I cleared my cache already, is there something extra I need to do?

Comment: What happens when you enter `https://example.com/uDoc?id=xx` in browser? Are there more rules in this htaccess?

Comment: It's very messy (as I said, when it comes to htaccess, I'm completely lost, but somehow this has been working for now(except the current issue of course)): 

http://pastebin.com/wRS55icS

Comment: I had 2 parts in my previous comment. Please respond to first one as well?

Comment: Oh yes - It's the same result.

Comment: Why do you have `RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]` line at the top? Comment it out and change above rule to `RewriteRule ^uDoc/?$ display.php?type=doc [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: But this line is essential as it converts, for example: example.com/uDocs to example.com/uDocs.php

Without it, everything using that would result in a 404 error

Comment: Doesn't `display.php` also exist? If yes then move `.php` rule at the end of .htaccess

Comment: Hmm, putting it at the end changes nothing :/

But I'll update the question itself to reflect the problem.